# Moving point feature and vertex from polyline at the same time

Tags: qgis-3, topology, vertices, move

I have two layers in QGIS 3.14:

- one with point geometry
- one with polyline geometry

The point geometries (p) have the same coordinates as some of the polyline vertices (v):

(v)--------(v)----------**(v/p)**--------(v)-------------(v)----(v/p)-------(v/p)

Now I want to move a point geometry AND the vertex from the line at this point (v/p) to another coordinate:

(v)--------(v)-----------------**(v/p)**-(v)-------------(v)----(v/p)-------(v/p)

Is it possible to do this in **one action**? I think there must be a way to *"connect"* both layers, but I didn't find a function or a tool or a documentation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to:

1. Click on the Enable Topological Editing button in the Snapping toolbar.

   [image]
2. Start the edit session on both your point and line layers.
3. Click on `Vertex Tool (All layers)` (although, `Vertex Tool (Current layer)` also worked for me).

   [image]

This enables a tool that you can use to move a common vertex in both point and line layers, as you can see in this GIF:

[image]